# How is it decided whether a system is complete/consistent (specific case)?

Tags: incompleteness, decidability

In a [paper by Barrow](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0612253.pdf) a table is produced explaining whether certain systems are complete/consistent. The following table is presented:

[image]

As I understand, none of these results are proved internally. This would mean, for a formal proof of the results one would have to resort to set theory or something similar. That being said, the way the proofs are formulated seem to resort to "common sense", rather than any formal system.

But if we nonetheless say that the results are proven/provable in set theory, Peano-Axioms (or "arithmetic") are proven to be consistent in set theory. So why are the two question marks presented? Should the answer not be "YES"?

Comment: This is curious. Which version of "Euclidean geometry" is he considering?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo The paper doesn't say, but he must be referring to Tarski's formulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, there is an implicit assumption of a background theory here. ZFC is one possibility, but there are others; it looks to me like the author is taking as their background theory Peano arithmetic. (Indeed, if we are truly confident in PA then we must expect PA to never be able to fill in the "??.")

That is, when they write a "yes" in the "Is [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) consistent?" box, what they mean is "PA proves that Presburger arithmetic is consistent." If we change the background theory, then of course we get a different chart.